# Populate dropdown with list of files and download when clicked

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

How can i populate dropdown lists with list of files in a folder and then when a user clicks on the name of the file they download it?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#2").empty();
    $("#3").empty();
    $("#4").empty();
    $btn1.hide();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/uploads/docs/' + "name" + ".pdf",
        type: 'HEAD',
        error: function () {
        },
        success: function () {
           e.preventDefault();  
           window.location.href = '/uploads/docs/' + "name" + ".pdf"; 
        }
    });  
 });
```

I have got this which can look in a folder but only for one pdf name and if it exists it downloads a download a pdf. But how do i populate the dropdown and use that? I need to have the user be able to donwload any sort of file .jps .exe etc thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think easiest way to do this is create a model with properties File Name & File Path.(or you can use anonymous type with these properties)

```
public class File
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

create a file collection using your data in Controler

```
ViewBag.FileCollection = "your file collection";
```

then in your view use Html.DropDownList:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Files", new SelectList(ViewBag.FileCollection, "FilePath", "FileName"))
```

Nicola Peluchetti's answer has the client side code.

Comment: you can pass data from controler to view using viewbag.

Comment: but how do i make a list of files in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
<select id=yourSelect>
    <option value="">Choose a file</option>
    <option>File1</option>
    <option>File2</option>
    <option>File3</option>
</select>

$('#yourSelect').change(function() {
    var name = this.value;
    if (name !== "") {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to download " + name)) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/uploads/docs/' + name + ".pdf",
                type: 'HEAD',
                error: function() {},
                success: function() {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    window.location.href = '/uploads/docs/' + name + ".pdf";
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/G4wJV/

This tries to download `/uploads/docs/File1.pdf` when you choose the first option and so on

Comment: That bits fine, but i need to populate the dropdown with a list of files from that folder first?

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the directory is going to be changing often, you'll definitely have to do some work on the server side.

Using PHP, you'd create a script which first reads all the files in a directory using `opendir()` and `readdir()`. You'll probably want to read all the files in the directory into an array, and then sort them alphabetically using `sort()`, since they won't come in an alphabetical order. Then the script outputs the file list in HTML - for example, using a `<table>` or `<ul>`, where you can put standard file download links (`<a>` tags).

The output of the PHP file is then loaded using AJAX, and inserted into the page.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url:'/uploads/ajax.php',
        success: function(d) { $("#filelist-container").html(d) }
    }
);
```

Comment: ahh ok i was trying not to use server side, but i am using mvc3 .net

Comment: Well, I've always stayed away from that .NET stuff, but it should have the capabilities to generate a simple file listing - look it up in its manual.

Comment: Also, you can't really avoid doing something on the server-side in this scenario - the directory is on the server, and the JavaScript is executed solely in the client's browser.